# Django ForeignKey auto field

Tags: python, django

I have a `User` model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    SEX = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=100, blank=False)
    surname = models.CharField("Surname",max_length=150, blank=False)
    is_real = models.BooleanField("Real user", default=False)
    sex = models.CharField("Sex", max_length=1, choices=SEX)
    age = models.IntegerField("Age", blank=False)
```

Every `User` has an email or some:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    address = models.EmailField("Email Address", max_length=250)
    login = models.CharField("Login", max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField("Password", max_length=15)
    date_created = models.DateField("Registered", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField("Last login")
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Owner")
```

Also `User` may have a blog:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    address = models.URLField("Blog Url")
    related_email = models.ForeignKey(Email, verbose_name="Registered with")
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
```

Blogs are usually registered on email. So what I need is if I haven't specified an owner of a blog, it should be automatically set to an owner of a registration email. I think it could be done by overriding `save` method but not really sure how to cope with `ForeignKey` relations.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you do something like this?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.belongs_to:
        self.belongs_to = self.related_email.belongs_to
    return super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I was thinking of smth similar. I was doubting a little, but looked through the docs once again and yes, you are right. And what about `null=True` or `blank=True`?

Comment: Yes you should probably add `null=True` to `Blog.belongs_to`

Answer (score -1):

First, add `null = True` to `Blog.belongs_to`

Assuming that you know the owner of the registration email, you can do

```
owner = User.objects.get(field = value)
email = Email.objects.get(belongs_to = owner)
Blog.objects.create(address = ..., related_email = email, belongs_to = None)
```

And then should you need to do any updates, you can do

```
blog = Blog.objects.filter(related_email = email).filter(belongs_to__isnull = True)
blog.belongs_to = newUserObject
```